# I want to add a cooldown to a bot. I want them to choose the cooldown. PYTHON DISCORD

Tags: python, python-3.x, timer, discord, discord.py

Ex Someone sends a alot of texts to someone for 100seconds. I want them to have a 100second cooldown because they sent 100texts. I'm getting this error:

```
@commands.cooldown(1,{time}, commands.BucketType.user)
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

```
@client.command()
async def text(ctx, ip, port, time, method):
@commands.cooldown(1,f'{time}', commands.BucketType.user)
    url = f'N/A'
    response = requests.get(url)
    embed = discord.Embed()

    embed.title = 'Launched'
    print(f'{ip}')
    print(f'{port}')
    print(f'{time}')        
    print(f'{method}')
    embed.add_field(name = 'IP', value = ip, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name = 'PORT', value = port, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name = 'TIME', value = f'{time}', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name = 'METHOD', value = method, inline=False)
    print(ctx.author, 'in', ctx.guild)

    embed.set_author(name="Proll's Bot", icon_url=client.user.avatar_url)
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

Comment: im a new to python and mostly code in java script

Comment: Change the position of `async def` and `@commands.cooldown`

Comment: After a `def`, the following line needs to be indented. In your case it isn't. Please read up on basic Python syntax.

Comment: Like I said I’m new if you could fix the code and send it. It would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Change the positions of async def and @commands.cooldown as said by bdbd

```
@client.command()
@commands.cooldown(1,f'{time}', commands.BucketType.user)
async def text(ctx, ip, port, time, method):


    url = f'N/A'
    response = requests.get(url)
    embed = discord.Embed()

    embed.title = 'Launched'
    print(f'{ip}')
    print(f'{port}')
    print(f'{time}')        
    print(f'{method}')
    embed.add_field(name = 'IP', value = ip, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name = 'PORT', value = port, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name = 'TIME', value = f'{time}', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name = 'METHOD', value = method, inline=False)
    print(ctx.author, 'in', ctx.guild)

    embed.set_author(name="Proll's Bot", icon_url=client.user.avatar_url)
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

Comment: Then {time} will be undefined

Comment: You will have to define the time limit in seconds